# Storing frequency of random generated integers in array

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I'm trying to solve a problem with array's here, and I'm not too good with explaining stuff so please bear with me.

I need to make a code that computes "num" random integers in the range [0 .. range) and puts the frequency in arr[]. This is what I have so far.

/**Compute a random integer in the range [a .. b)*/

```
static int randomInteger(int a, int b) {
  int randomInt = ((int)(Math.random() * b) + a) ;
    return randomInt ;
```

/**Compute num random integers in the range [0 .. range) and put the
frequency in arr[].*/

```
static void doSingleTest( int[] arr2, int num, int range) {

    for (int i = 0; i< num ; i++) {
        int rand = randomInteger(0, range);
        arr2[rand] ++ ;
    }

}
```

Am I doing this right? I guess what I am wondering is what arr[rand]++ means. I know that it means that it's incrementing the value stored at element rand but does it account for the frequency?

The final goal is to make a histogram that uses that frequency.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I assume the way it works (although you haven't show initialization of arr2) is arr2 is of the same length as your range of values. Say you are generating a random number from 0 to 4. You create an array with 5 elements, each representing one of those numbers. Then you increment the index according to the random number. You'll end up with each element in arr2 having the total number of values for that integer. Don't try this with very large ranges and it also doesn't work as-is with ranges that don't start at 0.

Comment: The value stored at element rand is the frequency so yes, it's accounting for the frequency.  I'm not too familiar with Java but I would imagine you would somehow have to initialize the array up to max with 0 in each element for the increment to work?

Comment: Depends on what arr2 looks like, but yes it does increment the value stored there thus accounting for frequency. You are picking a random number and taking it as the index of the array and incrementing the value at that index essentially counting how many times that random number has been picked, assuming the array has elements in the range [a,b) in increments of one.

Comment: @CalebJoshuaMingle In fact Java arrays of primitive number types are automatically initialized with all elements as 0.

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand it a bit better now.